# Setting maximum number of lines entry on UITextView

Tags: ios, ipad, uitextfield

I would like to restrict the user of my `iPad` app to entering a maximum of 20 lines when outputted on the pdf. The user enters text into the `UITextView` (as shown below) and this is then later converted into a pdf document.

[image]

I realise that I will have to do a few of calculations depending on what text is entered as they type. Are there any methods that can help me out here? `textFieldDidEndEditing` only allows me to check after it has been entered.

Also, as this would be far simpler, is there a way of limiting the number of lines a `UITextField` can be?

Comment: You can use the `- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string` delegate method from the text field to return NO if the characters the user is about to enter would make the text too long. I know of no good way of making that determination, though.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You were close with the `textFieldDidEndEditing` delegate method.

A better way though is to respond to the `textView:shouldChangeTextInRange:replacementText:` delegate method and then see if the change that is about to happen would result in more lines that are allowed.

Here is an example on how to do that:

```
- (BOOL) textView:(UITextView *)textView
    shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text
{
    static const NSUInteger MAX_NUMBER_OF_LINES_ALLOWED = 3;

    NSMutableString *t = [NSMutableString stringWithString:
        self.textView.text];
    [t replaceCharactersInRange: range withString: text];

    NSUInteger numberOfLines = 0;
    for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < t.length; i++) {
        if ([[NSCharacterSet newlineCharacterSet]
                characterIsMember: [t characterAtIndex: i]]) {
            numberOfLines++;
        }
    }

    return (numberOfLines < MAX_NUMBER_OF_LINES_ALLOWED);
}
```

I put a complete example online at https://github.com/st3fan/StackOverflow/tree/master/TextViewWithLineLimit .. tested on iOS 7.0.2. Enjoy!

Comment: This won't help with wrapped lines, though, since it just looks for newline characters.

Comment: I have just looked at this and as Jesse says this does not take into account one long piece of wrapped text. Nevertheless it does show me how to check the text as the user is typing - thanks

Answer (score 4):

The following works with '\n' + wrapped line support.

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        self.AutoresizingMask   = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
        self.AutocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
        self.KeyboardAppearance = UIKeyboardAppearanceAlert;
        self.font               = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Avenir" size:14];

        self.maximumNumberOfLinesAllowed = 4;

        self.delegate           = self;
    }

    return self;
}


- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)aTextView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)aRange replacementText:(NSString*)aText
{
    NSMutableString *t = [NSMutableString stringWithString: self.text];
    [t replaceCharactersInRange: aRange withString: aText];

    // First check for standard '\n' (newline) type characters.
    NSUInteger numberOfLines = 0;
    for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < t.length; i++) {
        if ([[NSCharacterSet newlineCharacterSet] characterIsMember: [t characterAtIndex: i]]) {
            numberOfLines++;
        }
    }

    if (numberOfLines >= self.maximumNumberOfLinesAllowed)
        return NO;


    // Now check for word wrapping onto newline.
    NSAttributedString *t2 = [[NSAttributedString alloc]
                             initWithString:[NSMutableString stringWithString:t] attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:self.font}];

    __block NSInteger lineCount = 0;

    CGFloat maxWidth   = self.frame.size.width;
    NSLog(@"maxWidth = %.02f", maxWidth);

    NSTextContainer *tc = [[NSTextContainer alloc] initWithSize:CGSizeMake(maxWidth, CGFLOAT_MAX)];
    NSLayoutManager *lm = [[NSLayoutManager alloc] init];
    NSTextStorage   *ts = [[NSTextStorage alloc] initWithAttributedString:t2];
    [ts addLayoutManager:lm];
    [lm addTextContainer:tc];
    [lm enumerateLineFragmentsForGlyphRange:NSMakeRange(0,lm.numberOfGlyphs)
                                 usingBlock:^(CGRect rect,
                                              CGRect usedRect,
                                              NSTextContainer *textContainer,
                                              NSRange glyphRange,
                                              BOOL *stop)
     {
         lineCount++;
     }];

//    NSLog(@"%d", lineCount);

    return (lineCount <= self.maximumNumberOfLinesAllowed);

}
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you're setting `self.AutocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;`?

Comment: Not really.  It just is.  :)

Comment: The code works well — thank you. However, I found an edge case: 1. Set the maximum lines to say, TWO.  2. Type until the text overflows onto the end of the second line.  3. Press 'Return'. The newline will be permitted and it goes onto the THIRD line! EEK!

Answer (score 2):

To limit the number of lines in the UITextView, I just do :

In the following UITextViewDelegate method :

```
- (void)textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)textView
{
    NSUInteger maxNumberOfLines = 5;
    NSUInteger numLines = textView.contentSize.height/textView.font.lineHeight;
    if (numLines > maxNumberOfLines)
    {
        textView.text = [textView.text substringToIndex:textView.text.length - 1];
    }
}
```

Comment: This won't work reliably since it assumes the text you are adding is as the end. If you place the cursor in the middle of the string it allows you to add as many carriage returns as you want....

Answer (score -1):

much more easier is to do like:

Swift:

```
textView.textContainer.maximumNumberOfLines = 10;
textView.textContainer.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByTruncatingTail;
```

Obj-C:

```
textView.textContainer.maximumNumberOfLines = 10;
[textView.layoutManager textContainerChangedGeometry:textView.textContainer];
```